# Ionic 3 How to dynamically add attributes to items

Tags: html, angular, attributes, ionic3

In Ionic 3 you can add the following to an item to display it at the start or end of a row:

```
<ion-item item-start>Start</ion-item>
<ion-item item-end>End</ion-item>
```

However I would like to add this attribute dynamically. I could do something like this:

```
<ion-item item-start *ngIf="isStart">Start</ion-item>
<ion-item item-end *ngIf="!isStart">End</ion-item>
```

However I want to keep my HTML down to a minimum. Is there a way to add these dynamically?

Comment: item-start and item-end were designed to be used for things inside of ion-item (like icons or labels). If you want to control horizontal etc alignment inside of ion-row - you ideally want to use appropriate classes: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#horizontal-alignment

Comment: but to achieve what you want (dynamically change alignment) - I would use corresponding CSS class and add/remove that dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.start = true;
```

```html
<ion-item [attr.item-start]="(start)?'':undefined" [attr.item-end]="(!start)?'':undefined">Start</ion-item>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

TS:

```
this.start = true;
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item [item-start]="start" [item-end]="start">Element</ion-item>
```

Comment: I get 'item-start is not an attribute' error when trying this.

Comment: not sure... that's the way to add dynamic properties: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5186#issuecomment-192583967